# Where can I find a data set on the federal student loan debt since at least 1965?

Tags: data-request, usa, government, economics, education

As the title says, I'm not sure where I can find the data set I'm looking for. I'm trying to explore the relationships between inflation rate, total student enrollment, and total amount of student debt since 1965. I've been able to find numbers for 2007 onward, but nothing going back any further than that. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

check this:

> The National Student Loan Data System (NSLDS) is the national database
>   of information about loans and grants awarded to students under Title
>   IV of the Higher Education Act (HEA) of 1965

https://catalog.data.gov/dataset/national-student-loan-data-system

Comment: That was where I found the data going back to 2007. I might just be awful at navigating their website, but I couldn't find anything going back further than that. I'll definitely comb through it again though.